# Remove all zeros rows and columns, and replace them back in same locations using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have matrix `data` and I remove all zero rows and columns with

```matlab
data( ~all(data,2), : ) = [];
data( :, all(~data,1) ) = [];
```

After I extract the resultant matrix, now I want to replace those all-zero rows and columns back to the same locations, i.e., at same rows and same columns.

I realized that I need to get zero rows and zero columns indices to replace back. How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Can you explain why it isn't easier/better to simply overwrite the all zero row/cols with their replacements? Why do you need to delete those rows at all?

Comment: Actually I have an algorithm which works for a matrix without all-zero rows or columns. So I remove them 1st and run algorithm, then I get same size matrix with different entries (I do not explain this in here as same size). But I need to put back original all-zero rows and columns. This procedure still works for my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like it would be easier to keep `data` the way it is and just take the needed values out and then replace them later:

```
data=[1 0 1;0 1 0; 1 0 1];

values = data(data~=0);
values = values + 1;
data(data~=0) = values
```

**UPDATE**

The first part is for taking out every nonzero value. If it should only leave entire rows or colums of zeros and take out zeros too if they are in colums or rows with values it is:

```
data=[1 0 1 0;0 0 0 0;1 0 1 1];

values = data(any(data,2),any(data,1));
values = values + 1;
data(any(data,2),any(data,1)) = values
```

not that `data` has changed and the 0 in the upper right corner becomes a 1

Comment: Very straightforward approach, but I would use a stronger criteria for the non-zero elements. It should be at least `(data~=0)` to also capture negative values.

Comment: @Finn, nice code! I do not want to remove row or column with at least one zero, but row and column with all-zeros. Further, I need to get that resultant matrix separately,  and then add back those all-zeros rows and columns

Comment: The all zeros part is easy, I update the solution, but i am not entirely sure what you mean with 'resultant matrix'. If it is the matrix without the zero lines, that is in `values`

Answer (score 1):

For example, see comments for explanation:

```
A = rand(100,10);
% Make some rows zeros
A([1 2 10 80],:) = 0;

% make boolean array for your condition
bool_zeros = all(A == 0, 2);

% find indices corresponding to boolean array
ind_zeros = find(bool_zeros);
ind_non_zeros = find(~bool_zeros);

A_nozeros = A;
A_nozeros(bool_zeros,:) = [];

% your algortihm, e.g. division by itself, would not work for zeros
somefun = @(x) x./x;
A_output = somefun(A_nozeros);

% put zeros in again
A_output_with_zeros = A;
A_output_with_zeros(bool_non_zeros,:) = A_output
```

Comment: This also works for my task, and makes as a useful answer. @rinkert thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you explicitly want to restore deleted all-zero rows and columns in their original place, here's a solution exactly doing this. Basically, I store the row and column indices of the all-zero rows and columns. Then, the deletion itself takes place using these indices. Afterwards, I restore as many all-zero rows and columns as deleted before, and put them "at the end" of the original data. And finally, I determine the proper "permutation vectors" to rearrange all rows and columns. (Maybe, pen and paper is useful to follow the linear algebra.)

Here's the code:

```matlab
% Set up test data.
data = 10 * rand(5);
data(data < 8) = 0

% Save original data for later comparison.
dataOrig = data;

% Find row and column indices off all-zero rows/columns.
rowIdx = find(all(~data, 2)).'
colIdx = find(all(~data, 1))
nRows = numel(rowIdx);
nCols = numel(colIdx);

% Remove all-zero rows/columns.
data(rowIdx, :) = [];
data(:, colIdx) = []

%%% Here goes your own function only working on the "cleaned" data.
% data = yourFunction(data)

% Restore all-zero rows/columns "at the end".
[rows, cols] = size(data);
data = [data; zeros(nRows, cols)];
data = [data, zeros(rows+nRows, nCols)];

% Restore original row and column order.
[rows, cols] = size(data);
permRow([rowIdx, setdiff(1:rows, rowIdx)]) = [(rows-nRows+1):rows, 1:(rows-nRows)]
permCol([colIdx, setdiff(1:cols, colIdx)]) = [(cols-nCols+1):cols, 1:(cols-nCols)]
data = data(permRow, permCol)

% Comparison
all(dataOrig(:) == data(:))
```

And, the output for a run:

```matlab
data =
   0.0000   0.0000   8.9283   0.0000   8.6185
   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   8.2942   0.0000
   0.0000   8.0730   0.0000   0.0000   8.6491

rowIdx =
   2   3

colIdx =  
   1

data =
   0.0000   8.9283   0.0000   8.6185
   0.0000   0.0000   8.2942   0.0000
   8.0730   0.0000   0.0000   8.6491

permRow =
   1   4   5   2   3

permCol =
   5   1   2   3   4

data =
   0.0000   0.0000   8.9283   0.0000   8.6185
   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   8.2942   0.0000
   0.0000   8.0730   0.0000   0.0000   8.6491

ans = 
   1
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This also works for my task, and makes as a useful answer. @HansHirse thanks!